# Zooming and rotating in on an area of the JavaFX canvas

Tags: canvas, javafx, rotation, zooming

I have simplified my problem to the fundamentals (the real problem is more complicated than this but a solution to this could easily be generalized to my problem).

I am working with JavaFX canvas and I am working on a feature that, when a button is pressed, the canvas will zoom and rotate in on an area. The initial canvas is as follows:

[image: Canvas Pre Rotation and Zoom]

The desired canvas is as follows, I hope it is clear that this would be obtained by zooming and rotating in on the mid-point between the nodes, the degree of rotation would be relative to the angle of the edge between the nodes.

[image: Canvas Post Rotation and Zoom]

Does JavaFX canvas support this functionality? How would this functionality be achieved?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This can be achieved, but of course it requires redrawing the content. It's much easier to do this with `Shape`s as mipa points out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality can be achieved by not using canas. Instead you should use the scene-graph where this can be achieved easily by modifying the transform of a group node.